# Creating bandwidth of link in ns2

Tags: ns2

i have a exercise about ns2. It requires creating bandwidth of link up 33% after 30s. Please, help me. Can you give me a procedure to run it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with following procedure.

```
proc myproc { } {
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1.3Mb 10ms DropTail
}
```

and call it after 30 sec.

```
$ns at 30.0 myproc
```

here initial b/w was 1Mb and after calling this proc, b/w will be 1.3Mb.